# Elasticsearch: Search in keywords ignoring case and accent (via aggregation)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I can search for specific keywords on indexes like this:

```
GET */_search/?
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "TECH.keyword": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TECH.keyword",
        "include": ".*mine.*",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this query, I can get all entries that have "mine" in their `TECH.keyword` fields, ordered by `"_count": "desc"`. So, it's OK.

The actual problem is that the index can contain `mine`, `Mine` or `MINE` or even `miné` in `TECH.keyword` fields. And I would like to return them all.

Is there a way to search in keywords ignoring case and accent?

The current mapping is:

```
"TECH": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a `normalizer`. You can't use an `analyzer` on `keyword` fields, but you can use a `normalizer`. It allows you to use `lowercase` and `asciifolding`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/normalizer.html

> ```
> PUT index
> {
>   "settings": {
>     "analysis": {
>       "normalizer": {
>         "my_normalizer": {
>           "type": "custom",
>           "char_filter": [],
>           "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "mappings": {
>     "_doc": {
>       "properties": {
>         "foo": {
>           "type": "keyword",
>           "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Ok thanks! +1. So I have to rebuild the whole index? (drop data, create mapping then import data)

Comment: You'll need to set up a new index, but you can create the new index with your updated mapping and then use the [`_reindex` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to move your data over. Also, if you aren't using them already, [`aliases`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/indices-aliases.html) are very helpful.

Comment: Wah! Thanks a lot! It will save me some time!